# Create Sub-Domain in same project on local using wamp

Tags: php, laravel, subdomain, virtualhost, wampserver

I want to create multi subdomain in same project on local using wamp like main domain - `localhost.mysite.com` and subdomain - `yash.localhost.mysite.com`.

I have tried my link but still not working, current code is :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost.blog.com
 ServerAlias *.localhost.blog.com
 DocumentRoot "C:/wamp64/www/blog/"
 <Directory "C:/wamp64/www/blog/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

## Virtual hosts

Include `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

Enable the `alias_module` and `vhost_alias_module` for `apache`.

following http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/

Comment: Have you setup `localhost.blog.com` in your hosts file? (You can check by running `ping localhost.blog.com` in your terminal to see if it returns localhost/127.0.0.1).

Also I would remove Deny from all

Comment: yes i have setup localhost.blog.com in hosts file as well and it is working properly but subdomain is not working

Comment: Before `</VirtualHost>` add the following two lines. `CustomLog C:/path/to/logs/localhost.blog.com-access.log combined` and `ErrorLog C:/path/to/logs/localhost.blog.com-error.log` and restart your servers. Then after trying to access the subdomain check the logs to see any relevant error messages. (Update the path to a directory where you wish to store the logs)

Comment: I have added these two line and these two files have been created that path but nothing is showing
Only com-errorlog showing
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2018:18:11:37 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"

Now i have changed localhost.vibrant-invitations.com  to  localhost.vibrant-invitations.com.

http://prntscr.com/j2v66r showing this when using subdomain

Comment: I have added these two line and these two files have been created that path but nothing is showing Only com-errorlog showing 127.0.0.1 - - [09/Apr/2018:18:11:37 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36" Now i have changed localhost.vibrant-invitations.com to localhost.vibrant-invitations.com. prntscr.com/j2v66r showing this when using subdomain

Comment: Status code `200` is a successful request so for your first attempt the virtual host was working. Change your alias from `ServerAlias *.localhost.blog.com` to `ServerAlias yash.localhost.blog.com` and ensure you have this set up in your hosts file as `yash.localhost.blog.com` and try again.

Comment: Yes, it is working if i set up yash.localhost.blog.com in the hosts file (127.0.0.1       yash.localhost.blog.com) but i want to create dynamically for every users.

Comment: please answer if anyone knows about this subdomain issue.